# Wordpress Permalinks structure taxonomy_termname/post_name

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am developing a website and I registered a custom post type called Book and taxonomy Genre for it. I want a permalink to be like 
www.mysite.com/genre_name/post_name

Code:

```
register_post_type( 'reviews', array(
    'label' => 'Books',
    'description' => '', 
    'public' => true, 
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'capability_type' => 'page', 
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book'), 
    'query_var' => true, 
    'exclude_from_search' => false, 
    'supports' => array( 'title','editor','page-attributes', 'comments', 'author', 'revisions' ) 
    ) 
);
```

What should I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share you registered custom post type code

Comment: register_post_type(
 'reviews', 
 array( 
  'label' => 'Books',
  'description' => '',
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'page',
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book'),
  'query_var' => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => false,
  'supports' => array(
   'title','editor','page-attributes', 'comments', 'author', 'revisions'
  )
 )
);

Comment: Update - I have also created a handler which return a specific url. Handler is registered using post_type_link. when i visit the page, it shows page not found.

Comment: Preetam, I've had more success using the structure `custom_post_type_slug/taxonomy_term_name/post_name` than this, I find Wordpress doesn't behave as consistently as I'd hoped when trying to achieve your requirements.

Comment: can you show some part of code? how you achieve this? I will get some directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by creating custom handler for post_type_link and pre_get_posts.

I prepared url as my client expecting using post_type_link.

I added rewrite rules for each taxonomy term i wanted. and flush the rules.

This way it works.

Answer (score 1):

While registering custom post type, pass this given argument

```
'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'genre_name' ),
```

Then update your permalinks. This will rewrite the slug name instead of custom post type name

Comment: can "genre_name" will come dynamically according to each post? It will be better to have assigned genre name instead of hard-coded word "genre_name"

Comment: Bro, I tried this code, its showing a default word in the URL. Can we do it dynamic slug name?